# How to deploy a Rails app with Capistrano (different Ruby version on the server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

My server has Ruby 2.6.5 and there are some Rails applications which run on this server. I would like to deploy another Rails application to this server. My local machine (development machine) has Ruby 3.1.2 which is installed by `rbenv`. I use Capistrano to be able to deploy.

Questions:

1. Should I install Ruby 3.1.2 on my server to be able to deploy my new application?
2. which version of Ruby should be set inside `deploy.rb` file in Capistrano for `rbenv`? It should be my server Ruby version or my local Ruby version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be developing/testing on another Ruby version as this is known to cause problems when the code is actually deployed. You want to find out about incompatibilities or inconsistencies by tanking your production server.

This is very likely if you're not even using the same major version. Between Ruby 2.6 and 3.0 there was a lot of changes to how keyword arguments are handled and new features were introduced like argument forwarding which are breaking changes.

You need to achieve [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) either by changing the Ruby version used in the production environment or development/testing so that they match.

> Should I install ruby 3.1.2 on my server to be able to deploy my new application?

Yes. Ruby 2.6 was EOL:ed 31 Mar 2022.

Comment: Thanks for answer , if I install ruby 3.1.2 on my server as well and choose this version as default then I might be able to deploy my new app but question is : Do my old applications which works with ruby 2.6.5 work on my server  after I install ruby 3.1.2?

Comment: Ruby 3 breaks a lot of gems so its very likely that they won't work. You should take @DemetrisConstantinou's advice and install RBenv on the production server so that you can run multiple versions of Ruby on the production server and not break your legacy applications.

Comment: You then need to consider when and how you're going to update the legacy applications.

Comment: My server has rvm installed. I think I can install another ruby on my server with rvm as well. There is ruby-version file in all my app on the server. In this case if I install ruby 3 on my server by rvm then choose it as default while I keep ruby 2 as well then my legacy app and the new app can work together on the server ?

Comment: yes, RVM and RBenv do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Then I install ruby 3 on my server and choose it as default then I will be able to deploy my new app to server. Because I run multiple version of ruby on my server my legacy apps and new one work together on my server. Is there anything else I have to consider before start this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is better to use same version of Ruby for development and production in order to avoid unforeseen problems. If not exactly the same at least versions should be close. 2.6.5 and 3.1.2 were released 3 years apart.

I would suggest to install rbenv on your server as well and use `capistrano-rbenv` found here https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv in order to deploy using capistrano and rbenv to match the version you are developing.

To conclude, using rbenv and capistrano-rbenv to deploy, you should use the same version of Ruby for both development and production.